My private key got exposed, did this happen to anyone else?
Private key got exposed, no idea how...
Hello everyone,
I was solving some challenges on Etherenaut when I discovered some weird transactions on 2 of my accounts on MetaMask wallet. It appears I have been hacked, no idea how it happened and weirdest part of it all is that my main identity account on which I recently had around 500$ of Ethereum is still untouched?
I found out when I realised all Sepolia Eth that I send to those account disappears instantly. I am very lucky not to lose real money.
Did this happen to anyone else and if so did you discover how?
Edit: And weriedest part of it is that I have transaction aging several years and I cannot recall haing this wallet back then, did hash algorithm collision happen?
Here is the account history:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
https://etherscan.io/address/0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8

How were the accounts generated? Through Metamask seed phrase?

The same thing happened to me on Sepolia ETH. And would you look at that, it's the same Account address: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
For context I created a brand new Metamask wallet account, I have an account 1 on there and that compromised address as Account 2 (shows as imported, although I have no recollection of doing so). Just like you, I got curious...
Turns out that wallet address is derived from this publicly used private key: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
If you search that private key in Google you will see that it is in one of the Patrick Collins tutorials, used to set up local Anvil networks, etc. At some point you (and I) must have imported that private key into Metamask for testing.
Any test ETH sent to that account will immediately get hijacked. A nice reminder in the web3 space to be careful with your keys! I'm sure you might have figured it out by now, but I just wanted to reply in case someone else has the same question.
